# Взаимоблокировки dll библиотеки (C# Framework dll)

Tags: c#, dll, async-await, deadlock, mef

Коллеги, доброго времени суток!

Весь мой код написан на C# (Тело программы и вспомогательные библиотеки)
В моем консольном приложении имеются библиотеки(шлюзов) к которым я периодически обращаюсь для выполнения тех или иных запросов к сторонним сервисам. Но выглядит что я столкнулся с взаимоблокировками и на тестовой среде никак не могу их воспроизвести для отладки. (на бою взаимоблокировки бывают чаще поэтому сейчас мне приходится realtime мониторить что у меня на бою)
Может есть предложения как воспроизвести взаимоблокировку dll (написанной на C#).

Обычно к одной библиотеке обращается по 5 потоков порой до 20, но в какие-то моменты что-то идет не так и сегодня наблюдал по логам как выполнялся код, выполнялся в библиотеке и был внезапно остановлен по сути на пустом месте при присвоении данных переменной которая является локальной для метода в котором было присвоение.

Подскажите с чего начать отладку. (Может можно как то разблокировать библиотеку если обнаружил проблему)

Пример того как выбираю необходимую библиотеку и обращаюсь к её методу

```
IPlugin gateway = (from plugin in plugins.Gateways where plugin.HowCode == "need_how_code" select plugin).First().CreateNewInstance();
gateway.RunOperation(command, param); ///Вот тут начинаются проблемы
```

Пример того как загружаю библиотеки при инициализации программы в некую переменную plugins. (при параллельном выборе проблем не возникает!)

```
[ImportMany(typeof (IPlugin))]
private IPlugin[] plugins;
```

```
public void Load() 
{
    
    try
    {
        CompositionContainer compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(
            new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, gatewayPath), "*.dll"), 
            new ExportProvider[0]);

        CompositionBatch batch1 = new CompositionBatch();
        batch1.AddPart(this);
        CompositionBatch batch2 = batch1;
        compositionContainer.Compose(batch2);
        string[] strArray = new string[plugins.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (IPlugin plugin in plugins)
        {
            string how = plugin.How;
            strArray[index] = plugin.How;
            ++index;
        }
        Config.Hows = string.Join(",", strArray);
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message + "\r\n";
        foreach (Exception loaderException in ex.LoaderExceptions)
            message = message + loaderException.Message + "\r\n";
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Ошибка загрузки [для " + ex.Source + " " + ex.Message + "]");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Ошибка загрузки шлюза. [" + ex.Message + "]");
    }
}

/// 
public void RunOperation(Command command, string param)
        {
            switch (command)
            {
                case Command.get_log: 
                    operation = new GetLog(param);
                    break;
                case Command.config_update: 
                    operation = new ConfigUpdate(param);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exeption(Errors.UNKNOW_COMMAND);
            }
            operation.Start();
        }
```

Comment: `plugins` - поле, а не локальная переменная. Дедлок возникает внутри `RunOperation`? Покажите этот метод.

Comment: Добавил метод RunOperation в описание задачи. Дело в том что кода там уже много и для каждого шлюза RunOperation свой собственный, весь проект предоставить не могу. (а то что сейчас предоставил явно не внесет ясности в решение вопроса, но к сожалению больше информации предоставить не могу и упростить код для того чтобы предоставить его здесь тоже не могу, разросся проект...).

Answer (score 1):

> *сегодня наблюдал по логам как выполнялся код, выполнялся в библиотеке и был внезапно остановлен по сути на пустом месте при присвоении данных переменной которая является локальной для метода в котором было присвоение*

Выполнение синхронного кода по присвоению переменной не может вызвать или попасть в блокировку. Блокировка скорее всего где-то не там, куда вы смотрели, например в каком-то другом потоке.

Взаимоблокировка называется **deadlock**, по этому ключевому слову можно найти очень много всего почитать.

И чаще всего взаимоблокировка находится не отладкой, особенно если она не гарантированная, а ситуативная, а анализом кода.

Смотрите те места, где вы ставите `lock`, есть ли внутри операции, которые могут быть залочены другим локом. Будет ли гарантированный выход из лока, или есть выход условный "пока не произойдет что-то там".

Вообще в асинхронном коде `lock` - штука не всегда хорошая, потому что он "вешает" текущий поток, в некоторых случаях лучше делать блокировку асинхронной, например с помощью `SemaphoreSlim`.

```csharp
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1)) // 1 - сколько потоков может войти в зону светофора одновременно
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoJobAsync(semaphore));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Запускаю 10 задач параллельно и жду завершения всех

```csharp
private async Task DoJobAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    // некритичный код

    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        // код критичной зоны, только одна задача может находиться здесь в один момент времени
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }

    // некритичный код
}
```

Плюс к нему еще можно `CancellationToken` прикрутить. И например при завершении работы приложения отменить все ожидающие задачи.

Так же, вы наверное уже в курсе, что внутри лока нельзя использовать асинхронный код. Внутри светофора - можно.

И наконец, если ничего не помогает, можно проверить, а не в синхронизации ли потоков дело

```csharp
await Task.Run(() => gateway.RunOperation(command, param));
```

Если дело действительно в попытке выполнить код на заблокированном потоке из другого потока, то этот код должен вылечить ваше приложение.

Comment: aepot подскажите возможно ли перед выполнением gateway.RunOperation как-то проверять библиотеку на блокировку? (я бы себе сейчас хотя бы уведомления мог отправлять и не мониторить постоянно работу программы)

Comment: @ArchiKu чтобы что-то на что-то проверить, нужен критерий проверки. Выработайте критерий проверки и проверяйте, без проблем. Например, таймаут какой-нибудь. Но гораздо эффективнее просто сразу написать код так, чтобы искомая проблема не возникала.